# Flutter: How to change theme from runtime?

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

I have 3 themes based on colours like a red theme, blue theme and a dark theme as well. I want to change the theme of the app while the app is running.

I want to show an alert dialog from where the user can select the color of the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you present an AlertDialog (using `await showDialog()`), there is a `Future<dynamic>` return value. So, have some buttons in the dialog that lets the user choose their theme. Once the user is done choosing the theme, return the chosen theme using `Navigator.of(context).pop(selectedTheme)`.

Wait for this value wherever you're showing the dialog like `final userSelectedTheme = await showDialog(...)`. Once you have the new value, then update whatever state model is holding the theme and your app should update accordingly.

Since themes are generally at the top-level of the app, you'll probably need something more than just stateful widgets if you aren't using anything else. I'd look into Provider if you aren't familiar with anything else:

https://pub.dev/packages/provider